# WCF Tracing Error: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I setup WCF service tracing because 1 client out of about 30 wasn't able to finish the connection to the server.  After setting up test case on that client, the WCF trace report gave me these exceptions:

> An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection

and then

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

I found [this MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/59bd34a1-47a6-478f-8be6-def2c6ae190e) and solution that applies to Windows 2000 Server and Terminal Services and offers a hotfix to fix the issue.

I'm using Windows 2003 Server, so the hotfix doesn't apply to me.  Does anyone know what is happening to this 1 client while the other 29 connect just fine?

Edit:
The client returns this exception when trying to open the connection to the server:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://endpointaddress/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Comment: I once had a WCF connection issue on a single client, but I don't remember if it was the same. In that case, it turned out to be that the machine had a static IP address that it should not have had. It duplicated another on the network or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jay, I can access the client remotely, another WCF client on that machine is connecting to a completely different WCF service on a different server which is working fine so this leads me to believe something with the server?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem. The core problem was the context in which the calls were made.

I had a lot of code that looked like this:

```
New()
{
    IPC_Server.LoadFirstSetOfData();
}

IPC_Server_LoadFirstSetOfData_Completed(Object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    IPC_Server.LoadSecondSetOfData();
}

IPC_Server_LoadSecondSetOfData_Completed(Object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowDataToUser();
}
```

The problem with this was that I was calling the 2nd IPC function while I was inside the 1st callback. For some reason, doing this "corrupts" the next call. By moving our IPC calls out of the callbacks, we resolved this issue.

Now *how* you choose to move calls out of the callbacks is up to you. Maybe a contract change? Having a timer that watches for the 1st callback to come in, then execute the 2nd IPC call from the timer? The choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer.  Unfortunately my connection never gets to the point where I can even make any interface calls.  This is the initial "Open" on the client to the server.  That's what fails for me.  This issue was solved somehow on the client end for 3 months and then recently it has come back up and doing it again.  Which makes me about 100% positive it's a client configuration problem either in the router or something.  It's very confusing and I don't know how to present the issue to the client to show that it's their problem and they need to change something.